# android 4.0 - How to get bottom menu button using theme black?

Tags: android

I am trying to create an android app that has the following:

- Theme set to @android:style/Theme.Black
- Bottom options menu button on all activities except for one.

I am trying to remove the bottom menu button from the activity that I do not want it to appear on by returning false in the OnCreateOptionsMenu method. This doesn't work...

So if I compile my app to target sdk version 14 the menu is gone from every activity...

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are thinking of the standard Android MENU button, this cannot be removed. Keep in mind that on many older phones, this is a hardware (physical) button.

I recommend reading the advice I received in the following link, regarding the MENU button and the various issues pertaining to the changes from earlier version of Android to ICS.

[Handling the missing MENU button in new versions of Android (3.x and up)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774317/the-missing-menu-button-in-honeycomb-and-ice-cream-sandwich)

Also, I would pay attention to the following official info from Google, and strongly considering rebuilding the app to not be dependent on the MENU button.

http://android-developers.blogspot.no/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html

> Not only should your apps stop relying on the hardware Menu button, but you should stop thinking about your activities using a “menu button” at all.