# Target and minimum Android versions support tablets

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest

I have some apps in Google play with the following in the manifest.

```
<uses-sdk   android:minSdkVersion="10" />
```

Now ,for every app in my developer console under Optimization tips it says this:

```
"Target and minimum Android versions support tablets"
```

What does this mean ? and also i have tried adding

```
<uses-sdk   android:minSdkVersion="10" 
                android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>
```

But after adding this there are some features not working properly in my application.

So i would like to know :"

1) What is it trying to say?

2) Does it means that "My apps are not being featured by google for tablets ?"

3) What is the advantage and disadvantage?

4) Why does "menu" button in the device vanishes after adding android:targetSdkVersion="16"?

5) How to overcome this, without affecting any changes to my app?

Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 4):

1) The target sdk version indicates the highest version that you have tested your app against. So it has to be at least 11 in order for Google Play to promote it as a tablet application.

2) So the answer to your second question is yes.

3) Without a target sdk specified, it defaults to the same value as the minimum sdk version. If that version is prior to HoneyComb, I expect your app may not be offered to tablet users at all.

4) The menu button was removed in API level 11 and replaced with the Action Bar. This is why it has disappeared in your version 16 build.

5) I think you will need to change your app to work with the Action Bar instead (which is backward compatible with versions prior to API 11). Check out the question below that provides far more information than I could go into here:

[Handling the missing MENU button in new versions of Android (3.x and up)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774317/handling-the-missing-menu-button-in-new-versions-of-android-3-x-and-up)

Comment: hey i am getting this "cannot generate texture from bitmap" which is causing my app to crash after adding android:targetSdkVersion="16", can you please help me how to solve this?

Comment: Is it a gif? Is so, try a png or jpg since there are some issues reported with gif support in API 16. If you are still having problems upgrading your app, please raise another question.