# Android: Missing overflow menu in Material Design

Tags: android, xml, material-design

My overflow menu is not appearing in my action bar/App bar (even running emulator) but it only appears in menu_main.xml. What can I do?

---

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mo.thesis">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

**app_bar.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
android:background="#ccc">


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.mo.thesis;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
 import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.view.MotionEvent;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

  private Toolbar toolbar;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


      toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
      setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

  }


  protected boolean onCreateOptionMenu(Menu menu) {

      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
      return true;

  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
      // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
      // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

      int id = item.getItemId();

      //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
      if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
          return true;
      }

      return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }


 }
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.mo.thesis.MainActivity">

<include
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    layout="@layout/app_bar" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="78dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="119dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml Screen Preview:**

[image: activity_main.xml]

**menu_main.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


   <item
       android:id="@+id/action_settings"
       android:title="@string/action_settings"
       android:orderInCategory="100"
       app:showAsAction="never" />
  </menu>
```

**menu_main.xml Screen Preview:**
[image: menu_main.xml Android Preview]

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accentColor</item>
    </style>



</resources>
```

Comment: Does it matter if you use AppCompatActivity instead of ActionBarActivity?

Comment: I'm following a tutorial that is why I'mm using ActionBarActivity

Comment: It would be nice if you provided a link to said tutorial, but I think I figured out the problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your menu is set to never show

```
 <item
      android:id="@+id/action_settings"
      android:title="@string/action_settings"
      android:orderInCategory="100"
      app:showAsAction="never" />
```

Change last line there to `"always"`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps, From your code did not found any issue.

There might be other issue ---

The on-screen overflow menu button only appears in the action bar on devices that lack an off-screen MENU button. Try pressing the MENU button on your device or emulator.

please read this [Menu Button - Missing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8780560/2826147) answer.

Comment: Hi there, sorry for the late reply. Nope not yet because base on the tutorial I am following......He has the overflow menu and we are using the same emulator device and same API