# Legacy app remap menu key

Tags: android, android-support-library, compatibility

I am working on a legacy app that used to open menu with the old Android menu button. On newer devices the menu opens when holding down the back key. Is there a way to remap this action so the menu opens when holding the multitask button?

Edit: App uses min sdk version 10

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling the missing MENU button in new versions of Android (3.x and up)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774317/handling-the-missing-menu-button-in-new-versions-of-android-3-x-and-up)

Comment: There is no guarantee that the menu will open even when holding down the back key; for example, on OnePlus 3T, the user can remap each button as he wishes. The only solution is to move the menu options somewhere on the screen, in your application.

Comment: @Adinia you're right. I just upped minsdk to 11 and now the app has an actionbar with the options button, i couldn't capture multitask button event.